# how to find in jmeter response time breakdown

Tags: jmeter

How to see the response break down time in Jmeter ? I can see the response time taken for a particular request. My requirement is to see the response time break down like in FireBug.
How to do this in jmeter ?

Comment: Try [this page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), and be more specific than 'like in FireBug' -- what metrics in particular are you looking for?

Comment: sorry for less details. In firebug we have TIMELINE which shows Response total time break down. The categorised items are DNS LookUP,connecting,sending,waiting,receiving. Actually my requirement is to do performance and load test. And I got "jmeter"  which gave me total response time but I want only the specific "server waiting" excluding the download time.